# Error: Expression resolves to an unused function (array with closure)

Tags: ios, swift

I got an error whith this code 'tasks.remove(at: 0)' in the project : **Expression resolves to an unused function**, but it worked with a playground. But when I changed tasks.removeAll(), it worked fine. I used Xcode9.4, and swift 4.1.

```
var tasks = [() -> Void]()

func aTask() {
    print("blablabla...")
}

tasks.append(aTask)
tasks.remove(at: 0)
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I just want to know why compiler show me the error.
@vacawama has been answered it. just add "_ = " before tasks.remove(at: 0), it worked fine. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tasks.remove(at: 0)` returns the element at position `0` in addition to mutating the `tasks` array.  Assign the result to `_` to ignore the result and appease the Swift compiler:

```
_ = tasks.remove(at: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick help.  it worked.  :)